# ServiceStack + SOAP + soapUI

Tags: soap, servicestack, soapui

I'm trying to get soapUI to recognize the types in my ServiceStack soap service.  I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong in the setup of the service.  Here is the WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="Soap12" 
    targetNamespace="https://something.com/service/types" 
    xmlns:svc="https://something.com/service/types" 
    xmlns:tns="https://something.com/service/types" 

    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" 
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
    xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" 
    xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" 
    xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
    xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">

    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType" />
  <xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI" />
  <xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary" />
  <xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean" />
  <xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte" />
  <xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime" />
  <xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal" />
  <xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double" />
  <xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float" />
  <xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int" />
  <xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long" />
  <xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName" />
  <xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short" />
  <xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
  <xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
  <xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong" />
  <xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
  <xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char" />
  <xs:simpleType name="char">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int" />
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration" />
  <xs:simpleType name="duration">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
      <xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?" />
      <xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S" />
      <xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid" />
  <xs:simpleType name="guid">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName" />
  <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID" />
  <xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF" />
</xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="IsAvailableRequestIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:IsAvailableRequest" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IsAvailableRequestOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:IsAvailableRequestResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>



    <wsdl:portType name="ISyncReply">
    <wsdl:operation name="IsAvailableRequest">
        <wsdl:input message="svc:IsAvailableRequestIn" />
        <wsdl:output message="svc:IsAvailableRequestOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:portType name="IOneWay">

    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply" type="svc:ISyncReply">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="IsAvailableRequest">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://something.com/service/types/IsAvailableRequest" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_IOneWay" type="svc:IOneWay">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="SyncReply">
        <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply" binding="svc:WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply">
            <soap:address location="http://beta.something.com/service/soap12" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

    <wsdl:service name="AsyncOneWay">
        <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_IOneWay" binding="svc:WSHttpBinding_IOneWay">
            <soap:address location="http://beta.something.com/service/soap12" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Notice that it doesn't include the type information (I dunno, should it?)  Here is the type schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomethingWeb" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomethingWeb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="IsAvailableRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ClientID" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Token" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="IsAvailableRequest" nillable="true" type="tns:IsAvailableRequest" />
  <xs:complexType name="IsAvailableResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Available" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfAvailableData" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ClientID" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Location" nillable="true" type="tns:Location" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Message" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Request" nillable="true" type="tns:IsAvailableRequest" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ReturnCode" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Token" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="IsAvailableResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:IsAvailableResponse" />
  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfAvailableData">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="AvailableData" nillable="true" type="tns:AvailableData" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ArrayOfAvailableData" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfAvailableData" />
  <xs:complexType name="AvailableData">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Code" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Label" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="AvailableData" nillable="true" type="tns:AvailableData" />
  <xs:complexType name="Location">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Result" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Location" nillable="true" type="tns:Location" />
</xs:schema>
```

How do I get soapUI (and by extension, other java code) to understand my schema?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem and sorted it out by adding a default namespace in AppHost via

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
    WsdlServiceNamespace = "http://my.new.namespace.com/types",
});
```

And decorating my models with

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://my.new.namespace.com/types")]
```

More details here: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support